# How to make separate groups of radio buttons in PHP

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I am having issues with radio buttons in my output. I want 2 radio buttons for each line of the query that is returned. I can display the radio buttons correctly, but all the radio buttons seem to be in the same group, so I can only select 1 out of all the radio buttons, instead of 1 for each query. I hope that makes sense.

My program is a football picks page. So it lists the home team/away team and then its going to give you 2 radio buttons. One will be the home team and one the away team. And then you just select which one you think will win. I just really need help with these radio buttons.

Here is my code right now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<title>games</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
<select name="weekNo">
<option value="1">week 1</option>
<option value="2">week 2</option>
<option value="3">week 3</option>
<option value="4">week 4</option>
<option value="5">week 5</option>
<option value="6">week 6</option>
<option value="7">week 7</option>
<option value="8">week 8</option>
<option value="9">week 9</option>
<option value="10">week 10</option>
<option value="11">week 11</option>
<option value="12">week 12</option>
<option value="13">week 13</option>
<option value="14">week 14</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Games" />
</form>
<br>
<hr>
<?php

 $conn = 
 or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) //submit button pressed
{
$query=NULL; //prevent compile error

$weekNum = $_POST['weekNo'];

    $query = "SELECT a.game_no AS game_number, a.home AS home_team,
            homeTeam.wins AS home_wins, homeTeam.losses AS home_losses,
            a.away AS away_team, awayTeam.wins AS away_wins,
            awayTeam.losses AS away_losses, a.spread AS spread
            FROM weekly_stats AS a
            INNER JOIN team AS homeTeam ON a.home = homeTeam.name
            INNER JOIN team AS awayTeam ON a.away = awayTeam.name
            WHERE a.week_no = $weekNum";
 $result = pg_query($query) or die ('Query failed: ' .pg_last_error());

    $query2 = "SELECT week_no, game_no FROM weekly_stats";
    $result2 = pg_query($query2) or die ('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

 // Printing results in HTML
 echo "<br>There are " . pg_num_rows($result) . " records found.\n<p></p>\n";
 echo "<table border=1>\n\t<tr>\n";

 for($i=0; $i<pg_num_fields($result); $i++)
 {
 echo "\t\t<th>" . pg_field_name($result, $i) . "</th>\n";
 }
 echo "\t\t<th>Picks</th>\n";

  echo "\t</tr>\n";

 while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC))
 {

    echo "\t<tr>\n";

    foreach ($line as $col_value)
    {
    echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }

    echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"picks\" value=\"home\">Home
  <input type=\"radio\" name=\"picks\" value=\"away\">Away</td>";


 echo "\t</tr>\n";
 }

 echo "</table>\n";
 // Free resultset
 pg_free_result($result);
 }
 // Closing connection
 pg_close($conn);

 ?> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Radio buttons with the same group name offer only one choice. If you want multiple choices while using the same group name, use checkboxes then a `foreach`.

Comment: All radio buttons with the same name are part of the same group.  If you want them to be in different groups they have to have different names.  Give the home and away radio for each row the same name

Comment: Use checkboxes for multiple choices.

Comment: Also, your `<input type=\"radio\" name=\"picks\" value=\"away\">` is outside the form tags.

Comment: Since you are apparently connecting through to an external mysql server, I would consider changing its password. It may be firewalled (I sure hope it is), but you seem to have posted its full address, username and password along with a piece of PHP that is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Can someone help me write this with checkboxes or radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Since you require the user to select either the home or away team based on who they feel will win, the I suppose you should reference the radio buttons of each row uniquely. Something like this

```
     echo "<br>There are " . pg_num_rows($result) . " records found.\n<p></p>\n";
     echo "<table border=1>\n\t<tr>\n";
     echo "<form method='POST'>";
     for($i=0; $i<pg_num_fields($result); $i++)
     {
        echo "\t\t<th>" . pg_field_name($result, $i) . "</th>\n";
     }
     echo "\t\t<th>Picks</th>\n";    
     echo "\t</tr>\n";    
     while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC))
     {    
        echo "\t<tr>\n";    
        foreach ($line as $col_value)
        {
           echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
        }
        $pick_val = "picks_".$line['id']; // based on the row id of the db table
        echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" name='$pick_val' value=\"home\">Home
        <input type=\"radio\" name='$pick_val' value=\"away\">Away</td>";
        echo "\t</tr>\n";
     }    
     echo "</table>\n";
     echo "</form>";
     // Free resultset
     pg_free_result($result);
     }
     // Closing connection
     pg_close($conn);    
?>
```

This will help you select Home or away team row wise.

Comment: It still doesnt work. It doesnt let me select a radio button for each row